# How to safely shutdown computer during boot sequence?

Tags: linux, console, reboot

Due to a [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=611239) my computer has stopped in the middle of the boot sequence, just waiting. If I type anything, it prints stuff like `^[[B`. I do not want to damage the files on the computer by pressing the power button.

Is there some way I can exit the boot sequence and go to a prompt so that I can type `shutdown -h now` or `reboot` to safely turn off or restart the system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [magic SysRq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq) key combinations. Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to kill the boot sequence. This might let the boot sequence progress until you get a login prompt, but it probably won't. If it doesn't, press the magic more-or-less-safe reboot combination: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (sync), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (unmount), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (reBoot).

Once your computer reboots, at the boot prompt, edit the kernel command line (the one that contains `/vmlinuz` or something similar) to add the parameter `init=/bin/sh` and boot. The system will boot straight into a shell without starting the problematic ACPI script. Remount the root filesystem read-write and disable the problematic script. Then reboot, and this time boot normally.

```
mount -o remount,rw /
nano /etc/init.d/eeepc-acpi-scripts
```

Comment: If by default `kernel.sysrq=16` (only sync allowed) one some distributions, is there some way to set it to `=1` from bootloader by passing something to kernel cmdline? Thanks.

Comment: @MarcusLinsner I don't think so. There's no kernel parameter for that specifically and I don't think there's a generic kernel parameter to set sysctl values. You have to call `sysctl` from within Linux. There may be a way to tell systemd to do it, I'm not familiar with systemd.

Comment: I've good news: I just looked at the source code and subsequently also found in the [doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt):  there is kernel boot arg `sysrq_always_enabled` which will ignore any `kernel.sysctl=` setting and have sysrq always enabled! I have tested this to work when `kernel.sysctl=0`; also tested that it doesn't work without `sysrq_always_enabled` when that =0. Note: I used `sysrq_always_enabled` instead of [`sysrq_always_enabled=1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309882/306023) as kernel boot arg.

Answer (score 2):

When you say you type things and get things back like "`^[[B`" I'm assuming that means you are in the terminal?  If so, lots of time you can stop processes by typing ``` control-X``control-C ```.  See if that works for you.

Comment: I am not at a terminal where one can type. I just see all of the text from the boot sequence. Typing `CTRL+x` or `CTRL+c` just prings `^X` and `^C`.