# Alt+SysRq+T not working / Where do SysRq commands print to?

Tags: arch-linux, magic-sysrq

My REISUB commands, and K, work flawlesly, but with T (it should print info about tasks), it prints nothing. H also doesn't work.

```
Alt+SysRQ+H
Alt+SysRQ+T
```

I tried in all tty's (even F10, which doesn't even have a login prompt), but nothing.

Things like K work all right, it kills the xserver and everything (handy, because it freezes all the time).

How to fix / where do they really print to?

I'm on Arch.

Comment: It could be disabled at kernel compile-time. What is the value of `CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ_DEFAULT_ENABLE` in your kernel config (in /boot/config-3.whatever) ?

Comment: @don_crissti I did that, got no response :( | @wurtel sorry, there's no such file. my /boot has only `grub  initramfs-linux-fallback.img  initramfs-linux.img  vmlinuz-linux`

Answer (score 10):

The default Arch Kernel should have the sysrq feature enabled in kernel (I'm using a custom one, but based the config on the default one). However, in the default kernel, the bitmask to control, which features of the sysrq keys are usable, is set to *0*. I believe it is set to *16* (*10000*) somewhere during the boot on Arch, but I'm not sure where.

Provided the sysrq setting is compiled in the running kernel, one can check quite easily via:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq 
16
```

In this example it is set to 16 (=only emergency sync is enabled).

One can easily enable all sysrq functionality:

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

You need to do this as root, since echo does not work with sudo. Alternatively:

```
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq > /dev/null
```

(the `> /dev/null` part is not strictly needed)

The sysrq configuration is explained in more detail in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html), and even in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Configuration).

Also, if the problem is indeed that the bitmask is set so that required combinations are disabled, you should get a notification is syslog (at least I do):

```
kernel: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't use a custom kernel in any of my Arch systems, but all of them report 16.

Comment: Yes, I just mentioned it in case I had accidentally changed this somewhere compared to the Arch stock kernel. Your finding verifies I hadn't =).

Comment: Your documentation link is dead.

Comment: @kasperd link fixed.

Answer (score 2):

From the Kernel section on the Arch Linux [Keyboard shortcuts wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_shortcuts)

> If you wish to have it enabled during boot, edit `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf` and insert the text `kernel.sysrq = 1`. If you want to make sure it will be enabled even before the partitions are mounted and in the initrd, then add `sysrq_always_enabled=1` to your kernel boot command line options.

Comment: Can use simply `sysrq_always_enabled` (without `=1`) according to the [doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) - I've tested this and can confirm ;-)