# How to ensure SysRq is always enabled regardless of the kernel.sysrq setting?

Tags: linux, kernel-parameters, magic-sysrq

Some Linux distributions have `kernel.sysrq=16` which means only <kbd>SysRq + s</kbd> (sync) is allowed. As an example: Fedora (25 and 28) has it set as such in `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf`

I had to create a file as `/etc/sysctl.d/95-sysrq.conf` where I manually set `kernel.sysrq=1` so it's available as soon as possible (but possibly not soon enough depending on situation):

```
$ grep -nHi sysrq /usr/lib/sysctl.d/* /etc/sysctl.d/*
/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf:16:# Use kernel.sysrq = 1 to allow all keys.
/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf:17:# See http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA/Sysrq for a list of values and keys.
/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf:18:kernel.sysrq = 16
/etc/sysctl.d/95-sysrq.conf:1:kernel.sysrq=1
```

**Is there a way to enable Sysrq from early boot, possibly also ignoring any setting for `kernel.sysrq`?**, for example adding a kernel boot parameter (e.g., `cat /proc/cmdline` for current ones) such as from the Grub boot menu (or in `xen.cfg`'s `kernel=` line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is kernel boot parameter `sysrq_always_enabled` according to the [doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt):

```
sysrq_always_enabled
            [KNL]
            Ignore sysrq setting - this boot parameter will
            neutralize any effect of /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq.
            Useful for debugging.
```

I have tested Sysrq to work(eg. help,sync) even when `kernel.sysctl=0` (so it's just as the doc above says), if I add kernel boot argument `sysrq_always_enabled` (note: it doesn't have to be [`sysrq_always_enabled=1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309882/306023)).
(to double check, I've also tested Sysrq to NOT work when `kernel.sysctl=0` and `sysrq_always_enabled` is NOT present in `/proc/cmdline`)
[Source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/tty/sysrq.c?id=2601dd392dd1cabd11935448c0afe3293feb27a3#n71) confirms it too.

Note: `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` is another way to read/write `kernel.sysrq`

For more info on sysrq: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/sysrq.html
(though `sysrq_always_enabled` is not mentioned there, but it is [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt))

**EDIT:** When `sysrq_always_enabled` is in effect, there is a dmesg line:

```
[    0.000000] sysrq: sysrq always enabled.
```